# Load textures dynamically with LOD

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes, geometry

I have setup a geometry nodes that lets me subdivide a plane based on camera distance, so as I get near it, I subdivide the vertices within the camera cull. At the same time, I use a texture to displace mesh.
My texture is a height map, and it is a huge one... so I was wondering If I can load different resolutions of this texture, and Load a "LOD" texture as my camera goes in or out of the mesh. FROM disk... I dont want to use lots of memory.
I mean, if my heigh map is 6000px wide , then , I can resample to: 500px, 1000px, 3000px, and use each resolution loading and unloading the images from disk based on the camera distance to the mesh.
I dont mind if I have to accomplish this in geonodes, material nodes (make some materials) or ....
Can you help me?
thanks

Its a Grid mesh, created with the Add Mesh->Grid or Plane
Iadd them the geonodes.

Comment: Rather than posting below (which is a place for answers), [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/264133/edit) your question. It's not clear what you mean by "grid objects". Grid nodes inside the geonode tree? Or objects added with Shift + A, M, P?

Comment: Its a Grid mesh, created with the Add Mesh->Grid or Plane
Iadd them the geonodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think an image sequence can be used for that...

I made two images:

- `logo1.jpg` - 32x32 (insignificant size),
- `logo2.jpg` - 22000x22000 (207 MB).

Now, being on frame 1, I made a plane with a shader:

[image]

An important thing to note here, that loading the small `logo1.jpg`, and setting the total frames of an image sequence to `2` didn't raise my memory usage and Blender kept being at ~223 MB RAM usage. So the other frame is not loaded just because it's in the image sequence.

Now I go to **frame 2**. Blender hangs. Memory usage grows over 7 GB, then falls abruptly below 5.5 GB, then slowly raises over 6.3 GB and falls abruptly to 2.146 GB and becomes interactive again after about a minute of thinking.

Now I go **back to frame 1**. The memory usage drops but a very little, to 2.1002 GB. After about 30 seconds of writing here, it drops to 1.0883 GB. Either Python's Garbage collector kicked in after a delay, or Blender released reserved memory after a delay. Still, not all memory got released. This is not a problem if Blender upon demand, allocates some memory for a given purpose (bitmap storage), and even if it never releases it until restarting the program, it still reuses the memory for next loaded files - e.g. there's no memory leak, the belly never shrinks to the original size, but is being reused.

So to test it, I added another image:

- `logo3.jpg` - 11000x11000 (47.3 MB)

And increased the *Frames* field to `3`.

The memory usage is at 1.0746 GB

I go to **frame 2**. Memory goes up to ~6.1 GB (didn't reach 7 GB this time), drops abruptly to ~ 4.5 GB (dropped lower than previously), raises up again to 5.3 GB, and drops abruptly to 1.1413 GB and Blender becomes responsive again. I don't know what the hell is going on.

I go to **frame 3**. Memory raises for a second over 2 GB and drops to 1.6 GB.

What a failure of measurement...

Let's try again, 5 images:

- `logo1.jpg` - 32x32 (insignificant size),
- `logo2.jpg` - 22000x22000 (207 MB).
- `logo3.jpg` - 22000x22000 (202 MB).
- `logo4.jpg` - 22000x22000 (202 MB).
- `logo5.jpg` - 22000x22000 (201 MB).

Change the *Frames* to `5`. Go to frame 1. Save the project. Close Blender, and open the project again. Memory usage is 202 MB, but after a moment drops to 194.5 MB..

Now set ending frame to `5`, and render animation.

Frame 1 renders immediately, and rendering of frame 2 starts. Memory jumps to 2 GB immediately, and after a few seconds jumps again over 6 GB and then raises barely above 7 GB, drops to 5.5 GB, goes up again over 6.3 GB, drops abruptly to 2 GB.

Rendering of frame 3 starts: the memory again grows over 7 GB, drops below 5.5 GB, and raises over 6.3 GB, drops suddenly to 2 GB.

Rendering of frame 4 starts. Memory usage up barely above 7.1 GB, down to 5.5 GB, up 6.33 GB and drops.

Rendering of frame 5 starts. Memory usage exceeds 7.1 GB slightly, drops, goes up again to 6.33 GB, then drops to 2.075 GB - the rendering finished.

I think it's safe to say that while the memory isn't completely released once an image is no longer used, it is being reused by the next images.

So how to use An Image Sequence together with Geometry Nodes? Well, there are severe limitations: there's no input controlling the *Offset* field, so you can't control it on per pixel, or even per-object basis. You can only control it on per-material basis, so if you have a number of textures, and a number of resolutions (lod levels) for each texture, each geometry with a unique [texture, resolution] combination requires to be assigned a separate material. The *Offset* field can be driven, so you can use a driver that dynamically decides on an offset, however, you can't just red it from geometry nodes, at least not in sandbox mode - unless you go for a trick like either the object in question having its dimension(s) controlled by an edge(s) which size communicates the LOD level required, or you could have a separate object, that reads the geometry of the main object and is the communicator...

I still need to see if you can just have a material that if not used, will not take up the memory, but since the image loaded to an image texture appears in the interface, I imagine in the very least it will come up with some nuisance like every now and then accidentally opening the image in the UV editor and hanging Blender for a while.

There's still a possible solution with Python, which is limitless...

**This is not a full answer.** Actually I plan to delete 95% of it, but for the time being your question lacks some details on what is your setup (e.g. how many objects you use, how many textures, how many LOD levels, how much the LOD levels can differ within a single geometry...) - without knowing those details I can only guess what can work for you.

I measured memory usage in Windows 10 in Task Manager. All values were displayed as MB, I converted them to GB assuming it uses SI, but Microsoft is known for being even internally inconsistent with unit usage...

Comment: Made a test and unused materials still take memory, so image sequence approach is the way to go.